# Square APIs for Canada and USA

Tags: square-connect

I have my application registered with square. I am using register APIs, square oauth and square connect APIs. My app will launch in Canada soon (currently its only available in US). Do I need to have a separate app registered with square for Canada support or the same app will do? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your app will work fine for canadian merchants.